Indefinite integral of the product of a Gaussian with the imaginary error function
I would like to find a closed form expression of the following indefinite integral:
$$ I = \int \textrm{d} x\: e^{-\alpha x^2}\: \textrm{erfi}(x)$$
where $\textrm{erfi}(x)$ is the imaginary error function and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}$.
Mathematica gives the following answer to the integral:
$$ I = \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{-\alpha}}\left(1+4\:\textrm{OwenT}\left[\textrm{i}\sqrt{-2\alpha}x,-\frac{1}{\sqrt{-\alpha}}\right]\right)+C$$
where $C$ is an arbitrary constant and the OwenT$(x,a)$ function is defined here. I am unable to make sense of this because I am integrating a real valued function and so expect a real valued function as the answer as well.
I would also be interested to know how to derive such an integral. I looked at a few tables of integrals of error functions but couldn't find what I need. For instance, similar integrals in the table by Ng and Geller are definite.

Start here.

@J.G. Could you elaborate?

I'd hoped to sort out the derivation, but the lack of documentation on the Owen $T$-function for imaginary arguments is sufficiently irritating that I'll set that aside for now. Instead, let's check to see whether the result from Mathematica is genuinely complex. For instance, if $x=1$ and $\alpha=2$ then the antiderivative evaluates to
$$-\frac{i \pi}{2\sqrt{2}}\Big[1-4\,T\left(2,\frac{-i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\Big]\approx -0.0744 - 0.627 i$$
which is indeed complex. On the other, if we take $x=2$ and $a=2$ then the result is instead
$$-\frac{i \pi}{2\sqrt{2}}\Big[1-4\,T\left(4,\frac{-i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\Big]\approx -0.00125 - 0.627 i$$
Note that antiderivatives evaluate to have the same imaginary part. Therefore, we apparently have the definite integral
$$\int_{1}^2 e^{-2x^2}\operatorname{erfi}(x)dx=-i\sqrt{2\pi}\left[T\left(4,\frac{-i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-T\left(2,\frac{-i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right]\approx 0.073129 $$
So while Mathematica's indefinite integral is not real-valued, the imaginary part is independent of (real) $x$ and thus cancels out when computing (real) definite integrals. Indeed, it appears that $T(x,\alpha)$ is purely imaginary so long as $\alpha $ is of the form $\alpha=i\beta$ with $\beta>1$. For this scenario, then, it appears one can use the somewhat simpler antiderivative
$$i\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{\alpha}}\textrm{OwenT}\left(\sqrt{2\alpha}x,\frac{i}{\sqrt{\alpha}}\right)$$
Alas, this is not the whole story: while $T(x,\alpha)$ is entire for all complex $x$, it's not well-defined at $\alpha=\pm i$. This ends up yielding branch cut singularities running from $\pm i$ to $\pm i\infty$. In terms of the given antiderivative, this corresponds to the range $-1\leq \alpha\leq 1$. Focusing on $1>\alpha>0$ and setting aside $\alpha=0,1$ for the moment, suppose we compare the values of $T(x,\alpha)$ across the branch cut. For instance, if $x=0$, $\alpha=1/2\pm i\epsilon $ then Mathematica's Limit command yields
$$T(0,1/2\pm i\epsilon)\to \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\tanh^{-1}(\sqrt{2})\pm  i\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$
There is thus a jump in the imaginary part as $\alpha$ crosses the real axis, as expected of a branch cut. Hence it's not clear how to isolate a real antiderivative if $-1<\alpha<1$.
What about $\alpha=0,1$? In these cases, Mathematica returns different results for the initial indefinite integration. If $\alpha=0$, the results are straightforward:
$$\int \operatorname{erfi}(x)dx=x \operatorname{erfi}(x)-\frac{e^{x^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}$$
The result for $\alpha=1$ is more exotic:
$$\int e^{-x^2} \operatorname{erfi}(x)dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}x^2{ _2}F_2\left(1,1;\frac{3}{2},2;-x^2\right)$$
where ${_2}F_2$ is a generalized hypergeometric function.  Mathematica has little to say about this hypergeometric function and thus I will not add much. But the fact this case is strange is not especially: the imaginary error function blows up like $e^{x^2}$, so the case $\alpha=1$ is balanced between suppressing this growth and allowing it  to dominate the integral.

Huh, that's a good observation. What does this mean? Should I be throwing away the imaginary part for the indefinite integral? I need the indefinite and not the definite integral since this is part of computing the particular solution to a second order ODE.

@SayakBhattacharjee It depends, I think, on what range of $\alpha$ you're interested in. If you're willing to work with real $\alpha>1$ then it should be sufficient to discard the imaginary part. But if $0<\alpha<1$ then branch-cut issues prevent a simple resolution. (The case of complex $\alpha$ or $\alpha<0$ provide other issues which I'll pass over in silence for now.)

I see. For my specific computation, I need the indefinite integrals for $\alpha=1/2, 1, 2,3$. I do know boundary conditions for $y(x)$ though, and so can probably set the constant of integration such that it cancels the imaginary part, even for $\alpha=1/2$. Thanks for the analysis though!
